# Diffing two directories well

Tags: diff, merge

I need to diff (and merge) two directories (practically same content, with a few extra inserted lines in one set of files). Alas, all diff programs I tried (kompare, diffmerge, kdiff3, diffuse, xxdiff, ) don't do a good job of showing the differences (screenshot from intellij idea); or are limited to diffing files (in which case I did not check if they do a better diff job). The two directories are: [A](https://github.com/vishvAsa/vedAH_yajuH/tree/content/vAjasaneyam/mAdhyandinam/shatapatha-brAhmaNam/weber-srotaH/sasvaram) and [B](https://github.com/vishvAsa/vedAH_yajuH/tree/content/vAjasaneyam/mAdhyandinam/shatapatha-brAhmaNam/weber-srotaH/sasvaram-alt) .

Could you recommend a good diff program to solve this problem (GUI strongly preferred, must be free to use)?

[image: Diff failure screenshot]

Comment: Have you considered `diff -ru A B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) for diffing both files and folders. It is a free and open-source GUI app and its UI is intuitive and very user-friendly. It is fast but can become slow when comparing directories with non-text files.

This is how the diff between your two folders appears in Meld:

[image]

And below is the comparison of one of the modified files with its corresponding original file as shown in Meld:

[image]